# Swift crash with multiple async call

Tags: swift

the application below crashes when the source code is executed in: 
 **u.VerificaPermesso(...)**, the application checks on a rest server of n calls node. The code is correct but crashes can you explain the reason to me? Calls are made to a rest node.js server that responds with a value of true or false and depending on that value is displayed or not.

**Swift Code:**

```
import UIKit

class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    var u: User = User()
    /* Genero L'UITabBarController creando le ViewController ed inserendole in un array! */
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame
        tabFrame.size.height = 60
        self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame
        hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()



        let MarcaTempoView = MarcaTempoViewController()
        MarcaTempoView.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Marca Tempo", image: UIImage(named: "clock.png")?.scaleImage(toSize: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)), tag: 0)

        let CantieriView = CantieriViewController()
        CantieriView.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Cantieri", image: UIImage(named: "home.png")?.scaleImage(toSize: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)), tag: 1)

        let ArticoliView = RicercaArticoliViewController()
        ArticoliView.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Articoli", image: UIImage(named: "articoli.png")?.scaleImage(toSize: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)), tag: 2)

        let UserView = UserViewController()
        UserView.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Utente", image: UIImage(named: "user.png")?.scaleImage(toSize: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)), tag: 3)

        let ClienteView = ClienteViewController()
        ClienteView.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Clienti", image: UIImage(named: "risorse_umane.png")?.scaleImage(toSize: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)), tag: 4)



        var viewControllerList = [MarcaTempoView, CantieriView, ArticoliView, ClienteView,UserView]

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            //Controllo permesso accesso cantieri
            let u = User()

            //Controllo permesso accesso marcatempo
            u.VerificaPermesso(TipologiaPermesso: "marcatempo", completion: { result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     if(result == "false") {
                    viewControllerList.removeAll(where:{ $0 is MarcaTempoViewController })

                    self.viewControllers = viewControllerList
                    }
                }
            });

            u.VerificaPermesso(TipologiaPermesso: "cantieri", completion: { result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if(result == "false") {
                       viewControllerList.removeAll(where:{ $0 is CantieriViewController })

                        self.viewControllers = viewControllerList
                    }
                }
            });

            //Controllo permesso accesso Articoli
            u.VerificaPermesso(TipologiaPermesso: "articoli", completion: { result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if(result == "false") {
                         viewControllerList.removeAll(where:{ $0 is RicercaArticoliViewController })

                        self.viewControllers = viewControllerList
                    }
                }
            });

            //Controllo permesso accesso Clienti
            u.VerificaPermesso(TipologiaPermesso: "clienti", completion: { result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if(result == "false") {
                       viewControllerList.removeAll(where:{ $0 is ClienteViewController })
                          self.viewControllers = viewControllerList
                    }
                }
            });





        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Comment: "The code is correct but crashes" Any error message when it crashes? Something like "invalid index/out of bounds" Also, what happens if  the "articoli" is return first, then the "magazzino"? Will index 5 still exists?

Comment: please share the error message you see in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is unbalanced calls to the remove here

```
viewControllerList.remove(at: 1)
viewControllerList.remove(at: 5)
```

meaning if array count is 6 when you remove say element at index 1 that means when you try to remove at 5  it will crash because max count now is 4

---

you can avoid using indices in remove e.x instead of `viewControllerList.remove(at: 0)`

```
viewControllerList.removeAll(where:{ $0 is MarcaTempoView })
```

Comment: there is no problem in async calls as i see in your code it should work as expected , also why not you make i call with all parameters and return an array of Bool values